# Was there a famous player in Real Madrid history that wore jersey number 26?

Tags: football, uniform

I search a lot for Real player that wore number 26 jersey,
Was there a famous player in Real Madrid history that wore jersey number 26?

Comment: It depends on how you define famous.

Comment: Why are you asking about that particular number?

Comment: Most Real Madrid players are probably famous to some extent.  If you supply some more context we can probably help further.

Comment: I think this is pretty unlikely in a La Liga team, given that the first team is limited to numbers 1 - 25. Number 26 would be a player in the reserve team, and hence not one of the big players.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how you define famous.

There were some, but I think no big stars:

- Rodríguez (since 2014)
- Javi Garcia (2006)
- Álvaro Arbeloa (2005)
- Guti (1995)

[Site with all the jersey numbers over the years (1995-96 to 2014-15)](http://www.myfootballfacts.com/real_madrid_squad_numbers.html?PageSpeed=noscript).

Also there are no high jersey numbers in the early years. At that time they were assigned consecutively or even alphabetically.